# Is a mislabeled box a False Positive in Pascal VOC metrics?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, evaluation, object-detection-api

I am using Tensorflow object-detection API for training a custom object detector. I have decided to use Pascal VOC 2010-2012 as my evaluation metric. Everything is working as it is supposed to, but I have an issue understanding the idea behind false positive results. According to the official document for [Pascal VOC challeng](http://host.robots.ox.ac.uk/pascal/VOC/voc2010/devkit_doc_08-May-2010.pdf)e, a false positive is when the IoU is smaller than the threshold(.5 for example). However, I couldn't find any source which mentions whether a mislabeled box with a high IoU is also considered a false positive or it will be classified as an ignored box (False Negative). Anyone knows where can I find some more data on this matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the definition found at: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/evaluation_protocols.md

> A detection is a "false positive" if it is neither a "true positive"
>   nor "ignored".

Have a look at this example(also borrowed from the site above):

In the picture below, it is clear that,for the upper left detection(where the detection is a car but the ground truth is a bus, the `IoU metric` is higher that 0.5).

However, due to the fact that the ground truth is a bus, yet the detection is a car, it is also considered a false positive.

***NOTE: Although the example above belongs to OID examples and not VOC, since the mAP is used in VOC evaluation, the same criteria should apply.

[image]

According to the snippet from below(which is taken from : http://host.robots.ox.ac.uk/pascal/VOC/voc2010/devkit_doc_08-May-2010.pdf)

> Detections are considered true or false positives based on the area of
>   overlap with ground truth bounding boxes. To be considered a correct
>   detection, the area of overlap ao between the predicted bounding box Bp and
>   ground truth bounding box Bgt must exceed 50%.

As the notion of False Negative is non-existent in case of object-detection(only at the segmentation level if you read the evaluation chapters for both object detection and segmentation), it is clear that the case that you outlined is considered a false positive.

Comment: Well this is Open Images V2 detection metric, not Pascal VOC. My question in specific is, if we consider the red box at top left corner of this image, will it be ignored in Pascal VOC or will it be a false positive.

Comment: There should not be any difference between the evaluation metrics in this case; Since the Pascal VOC works with mAP (mean average-precision) which in itself needs the computation of Precision(here the false positives) and Recall, I am more than certain it considers it a false positive ---- In the end, think about scenarios in which your model only predicts false positives but with IoU > 0.5. Evidently these should be taken into account.

Comment: But good point, they should have specified it like that. In the end, if you work on your own problem, you can define your own custom metric, which can be the same or a little bit different than those on OID/Pascal Voc.

Comment: I updated my comment in order to be more consistent.

Comment: based on their official document I am under the impression that they are considering such cases as false negative. Take a look at http://host.robots.ox.ac.uk/pascal/VOC/voc2010/devkit_doc_08-May-2010.pdf, section 4. My problem now is more of Basics problem, where I compare different standard evaluation methods.

Comment: Yes, I also ran into the same link now. The thing is, they mention "ground_truth" bounding box; although unclear, it is assumed here that in case of IoU > 0.5, both boxes should relate to the same class. And then be inference (no pun intented!), the answer is this one : yes, it is considered a false positive.

Comment: They say, as I stated above, that detections are either true or false positives ==> the concept of false negative is not taken into consideration at all.